# Facebook PHP API getLogOutUrl() not working

Tags: php, redirect, facebook-php-sdk, logout

I have a logout button on page.php that serves as a link, and when clicked, directs the the user to logout_facebook.php. The issue is that the log out never occurs, but instead just directs the user to the Facebook homepage. How do I fix this?

Sample Code

```
<?php

    require_once('engine/facebook/facebook.php');


    //Application Configurations (Facebook)
    $app_id ="XXXXXX";
    $app_secret="XXXXXXX";


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $app_id,
        'secret'    => $app_secret,
        'cookie'    => true
        ));

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array( 'next' => ($fbconfig['baseurl'].'logout.php') ));

    //on logout page
    setcookie('fbs_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', '.mydomain.com');
    session_destroy();
    header('Location:'.$logoutUrl);     
    /*$facebook->destroySession();
    header('Location: http://mydomain.com/index.php?lo=facebook&ad=1');*/


?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using $facebook->destroySession();
instead of session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

If it redirects to the Facebook homepage and after `facebook.com/logout.php`, that means something isn't configured correctly in your app settings or the `next` parameter.

Recheck in your app settings to see if you are allowed to redirect to other urls.